# Existence of $C$ such that $p(x) \leq p(y) + C$ for all $x \leq y$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Suppose I have a polynomial $p$ of order $n$, which we can assume is positive, i.e. if $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ then $a_n > 0$. I am interested in the existence or non-existence of a constant $C \geq 0$ such that $p(x) \leq p(y) + C$ for all $0 \leq x^n \leq y^n + K$ and with $x, y \geq 0$.

Here are some thoughts when $K = 0$ and hence $0 \leq x \leq y$. We let $A = \{0 \leq x \leq y\} \subset \mathbb R^2$, and I think I can reformulate by question as whether or not there exists a $C$ such that $f(x, y) = p(y) - p(x) + C \geq 0$ for all $(x, y) \in A$.

I can find a $C$ if the region is compact by continuity, say if $y \leq L$ for any $L$, and for $x \geq L$ where $L$ is sufficiently large, eventually $p(x)$ is increasing so $p(y) - p(x)$ for $y \geq x$. On the region $x \leq L$ and $y \geq L$, and for $L$ sufficiently large again, we have that $p(x)$ is bounded and $p(y)$ is positive so a $C$ exists here as well.

What if $K \neq 0$? In this case I can see the analogous argument with $0 \leq x \leq y + K'$ is not strong enough. (This we can obtain from the fact if $x^n \leq y^n + K$ then $x \leq (y^n + K)^{1/n} \leq y + K^{1/n}$.) For instance if $p(x) = x^2$ and $y = x - K'$ then $y^2 - x^2 = -2xK' + (K')^2$ which can be arbitrarily large and negative by taking $x \rightarrow \infty$. So it seems to me that control over what happens at top order is necessary (thus we need $x^n \leq y^n + K$ and not just $x \leq y + K'$), but I don't know how to put this argument correctly/nicely.

EDIT: Thanks to a comment below, an extra condition $x, y \geq 0$ has been imposed.

Comment: This question needs to be narrowed down a little bit. Even with $x^2-y^2\leq K$ there are polynomials whose differences are unbounded- for example $p(x)=x^2-2x$- $ p(x)-p(y)\to+\infty$ as $x,y\to\infty$ on the curve $x^2-y^2=K$.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think this is a counterexample. If $x^2 - y^2 = K$ then $p(x) - p(y) = K - 2(x-y)$. Since $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x + y) = K$, we have $x-y = K/(x + y)$ so as $x, y \rightarrow \infty$ the difference $x-y \rightarrow 0$, so $p(x) - p(y) \rightarrow K$. That said, negative lower order terms does seem to pose an issue to my argument above, since I can obtain $x - y \leq \sqrt{K}$, but cannot insert this into $K - 2(x-y)$ to obtain an upper bound.

Comment: It does pose a problem because there are two solutions to this constraint for $x$, of which one has $x<0$ and that is the one that creates a problem with boundedness, since for that branch $x-y=2x$ which diverges to positive infinity. The way the question has been posed doesn't necessarily say that $x\geq 0$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I had in mind $x, y \geq 0$ but didn't notice the $x^n \geq 0$ didn't imply this. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can find an upper bound for $p(x)-p(y)$ as follows:

First consider a decomposition of the polynomial into it's negative and positive coefficients

$$p(x)=p_+(x)+p_-(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{A}P_{i}x^{p_i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-A}Q_{i}x^{q_i}$$

where $P_i>0, Q_i<0$. Next, one can show that on each curve $x^n-y^n=K$, the function $p(x)-p(y)=p((y^n+K)^{1/n})-p(y)$ is bounded. Consider the function

$$f(y)=(y^n+K)^{m/n}-y^m$$

This function is monotonically decreasing for $y\geq 0$ and also $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(y)=0$ and it is bounded below and above by

$$0<f(y)\leq K^{m/n}$$

We can now write

$$p(x=(y^n+K)^{1/n})-p(y)=\sum_{i=1}^{A}P_{i}(x^{p_i}-y^{p_i})+\sum_{i=1}^{n-A}Q_{i}(x^{q_i}-y^{q_i})<\sum_{i=1}^AP_iK^{p_i/n}=p_+(K^{1/n})$$
and we conclude that in the interval $K\in(0,K_{\max})$, which spans the region $0\leq x^n-y^n\leq K_{max}~,~ x\geq0, y\geq 0$, the quantity of interest is bounded, and since $p_+$ is an increasing function for $K\geq 0$ the universal bound is

$$p(x)-p(y)<C:=p_+(K_{\max}^{1/n})$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I especially appreciate the explicit and intuitive bound $K^{m/n}$ on the lower order terms. :)